# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined for carroussel

Tags: javascript

i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" at line 12 i don't know why

```
class Slider {
duration = 0;
currentSlide = 0;
slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
constructor() {
    this.initSlide();  
}

initSlide() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
        this.currentSlide[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    this.currentSlide++;
    if (this.currentSlide > this.slides.length) {
        this.currentSlide = 1
    }    
    this.slides[this.currentSlide - 1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(this.initSlide, 3000); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `initSlide`-method, there you try to iterate over the list of elements, which have the class name `slide`.

Inside your loop you use `this.currentSlide` as an Array and you assume, that the array element is an html element that have the property style. But you declared the property currentSlide as type of number and you assigned a value of 0. You can not iterate over 0 or over a type of number.

The correct iteration should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
  this.slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

But I think, this is not what you wanted, right, but it solves your error.

EDIT: To avoid all following errors you have to check first if there are slides on the page:

```
if(this.slides.length >= 1) {
  this.slides[this.currentSlide - 1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

And use an arrow function, not the function itself to avoid that your inner this reference is pointing to the window object, instead to point to your generated object.

```
setTimeout(() => this.initSlide(), 3000);
```

Comment: yes, thanks but now i have the same issue with length at the previous line , sorry i just started to learn javascript 3 weeks ago, i'm just trying to understand.

Comment: @iceson To avoid all following and possible errors, see my edit.

Comment: thanks a lot for taking time to explain me. the caroussel is working.

Comment: @iceson Can you flag my answer then as the solution? Or was it an other thing, that helped you out?